# Find, with proof, the number of distinct graphs with the vertex set $V = \{1, 2, \ldots,n\}$

Tags: graphs, proof-techniques, combinatorics

Let $n \in \mathbb{Z^+}$. Find, with proof, the number of distinct graphs with the
vertex set $V = \{1, 2, \ldots,n\}$. We say two such graphs are distinct if one of them has an edge $(u, v)$ and the other one does not have this edge with the same vertices.

Comment: In the Math Section: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/154941/how-to-calculate-the-number-of-possible-connected-simple-graphs-with-n-labelle

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it is pure math and is a duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/154941/how-to-calculate-the-number-of-possible-connected-simple-graphs-with-n-labelle

Comment: @AndrejBauer That question requires the graph to be connected, so it's not a duplicate.

Comment: My bad. It still fits the math forum better.

Comment: @Raphael I have no idea where to begin. I have thought of basing my proof in the following manner though: Picking apart all $(u,v)$ from $V$ and forming separate graphs with each of them. This way neither of graphs have the same edge and an $n$(?) number of graphs could be formed. Does this sound correct?

Comment: That doesn't sound helpful at all. How are you *counting* things? Hint: Think of different graph representations you know and try to count *them*.

Comment: Also, while the linked question does not match perfectly, reading the answers may be of help.